# Mod_rewrite, first rule works perfectly, second rule does not

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two mod_rewrite rules, for defining a **category** and a **product**. Products are displayed in categories, and clicking on a product comes up with a product page:

1. This works:

`http://www.example.com/ELE/electricalgoods/` Where this takes the code value "ELE" and uses it with the rewrite to actually call `/view_category.php?cat=ELE`. This works perfectly, using the following mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /show_category.php?catcode=$1&page=$3 [NC]
```

(this also includes a further "folder" for pages in the category view such as `http://www.example.com/ELE/electricalgoods/3/`)

2. However, underneath this in my htaccess file I want to have a similar rewrite so:

`http://www.example.com/product/EL063/Earphones/` rewrites to: `/view_product.php?prodid=EL063`

I did this with this htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /show_product.php?prodid=$1 [NC,L]
```

But somehow this doesn't work as expected, I want the product to appear in the "product/" folder with the `"/product/<code>/<name>/"` layout, and calling the `/show_product.php` file.

What happens is that the call to the `view_product.php` page fails with a 404 error.

I have tried to rearrange my mod_rewrite rules and I have also tried variations on escaping / ancasing in brackets the `product/` segment of the URL call. 
I have also tried changing the `$1` to `$2` or `$3` incase the ordering of the codes has changed but that doesn't appear to work.

What am I doing wrong?

For clarity, here is my full htaccess code:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /show_product.php?prodid=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /view_category.php?catcode=$1&page=$3 [NC,L]
```

**Edit:** updated mod_rewrite code, issue persists even with `L` flags and reordering of rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it will always match the first rule `([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)`. Because that pretty much says in combination of 3 directories. You need to change the order. And add the L flag at the end to stop processing once that rule is met.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /show_product.php?prodid=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /view_category.php?catcode=$1&page=$3 [NC,L]
```